# knapsack with multiple constraints and some negative weights

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, constraints

I'm trying to solve an integer linear programming problem of the following form

$max$  $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i \cdot x_i$
$s.t. \sum_{i=1}^n w_{i1} \cdot x_i \leq 0$ and  $\sum_{i=1}^n w_{i2} \cdot x_i \leq 0$

where the $x_i \in \{0,1\}$, and the $w_{ij}$ and $v_{i}$ are integers (without a sign restriction). Now my question is whether this problem is a knapsack.

I have done some research into the problem and found for example this source
[Algorithms for Knapsack Problems](http://hjemmesider.diku.dk/~pisinger/95-1.pdf) quite helpful. He seems to suggest in chapter 1.3.1 that one can merge the constraints and replace them with

$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (w_{i1} + \lambda w_{i2}) x_{ij} \leq 0$

where $\lambda>0$ is chosen sufficiently large so that one constraint cannot "interfere" with the other. This is also nicely explained in this StackOverflow post [Multiple constraint knapsack problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827600/multiple-constraint-knapsack-problem).

I have an extra issue however, since my weights are not constrained to be nonnegative. Normally, one would get rid of these negative weights, using the standard trick of introducing pseudo $x_i$ which are already in your knapsack and then adjusting your knapsack capacity. (For more information about this trick, see e.g. page 15 in [Knapsack Problems: Algorithms and Computer Implementations](http://www.or.deis.unibo.it/kp/KnapsackProblems.pdf).)

In my case, since I have two constraints, with the $w_{i1}$ potentially of a different sign then $w_{i2}$ I cannot apply this trick, because one of the weights will still be negative. So even though the first link that I gave seems to suggest on page 16 that "Negative coefficients in the Knapsack model are easily handled", I don't think this still holds in my situation. Am I right? Or can my problem still be reformulated?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately I think you’re formulation is too general to admit reduction to standard knapsack.

Comment: Thanks @Bey! I'll try to use a general ilp solver instead.